# How to do instanceOf of a variable of a class (not a class type) in scala

Tags: scala, types

I want to use `isInstanceOf` to decide the type of a variable,
however `isInstanceOf[T]` requires T and T has to be a class decided in compile time. I hope I can make it a variable.

See the example code:

```
class A{ ... }
class B{ ... }

val class_map = Map( classOf[A] -> 1, classOf[B] -> 2 )
val a = new A()
class_map.keys foreach { i =>
   if (a.isInstanceOf[ i ])  // how to make this statement work?
     println(class_map[i])
}
```

Comment: `isInstanceOf` is usually a code smell, and this looks like an **XY Problem**, can you describe the broader problem you want yo solve. There may be better alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) method of the `Class` object:

```
val matchingValues = class_map.collect {
  case (clazz, value) if clazz.isInstance(a) => value
}

matchingValues foreach println
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd take a different approach, along the lines of:

```
sealed trait Arg
case class A{ ... } extends Arg
case class B{ ... } extends Arg

val class_map: Arg => Int = {
  case A => 1
  case B => 2
}

val a = new A()
println(class_map(a)) // will print 1
```

Comment: I don't think you can write `case A => 1`, if A is a class.

Comment: @worldterminator On the contrary, that's what pattern matching is for. But also, why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: @worldterminator apologies, I didn't realise those were not case classes :facepalm: . Once you make them so, it compiles and works (slightly adjusting the match block's syntax).